# App not installed...because its resources have been modified

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

One user cannot install my app because they continue to receive the error:

```
The application “myapp” was not installed on the iPhone “myPhone” because its resources have been modified
```

I've read the error occurs because of adding files after the app is built.  I have not added any files.  Last week, the user could install the ad hoc without issue.  I've tried clean and rebuilt with no luck.  As the developer, the ad hoc installs fine on my device from iTunes, even after deleting all profiles.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF this is an adhoc distribution, I'd clean and re-build it, then give it to the user again, along with the provisioning profile : basically make sure they have a clean set of everything.

There is also a reported issue on Vista / Win7 where windows corrupts the Zip. It may be worthwhile distributing it as a ipa file rather than a zip

Comment: I've cleaned and rebuilt.  I'm not zipping either.  Just straight .app file.

Comment: how are you distributing it ? Sounds like *something* is modifying the file before the user installs it. Try making it a zip or better still an ipa

Comment: I'm dropping the .app into a dropbox folder.  The recipient (Windows machine) gets the .app file out of the dropbox and drops into iTunes.  This is how we've always done it.

Comment: Well something is changing it. Perhaps dropbox touches it. Go on - zip it first! It may be a change to dropbox functionality that's causing this issue. I also distribute beta via DB, but always zip first.

Comment: I had this issue too on a Windows 7 machine and can confirm that this is an issue with Windows corrupting the Zip. I solved this by distributing the app as an ipa... and if anyone doesn't know how to do that (like I didn't!), then this link will help: http://www.iphonedevsample.com/2010/03/15/solution-for-itunes-error-resources-have-been-modified/  I followed these steps and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was the .Double files being added to every directory on a shared network drive. We are primarily a Windows environment, and the Mac was saving .Double files on the drive, in every directory.

Literally, to fix the issue referenced above, I simply deleted the .Double files in every directory (of the app being copied to iTunes) and it fixed it.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

This issue also occurs when the person trying to install the .app file has double clicked on the appname.app folder (its shown as a folder in windows environment). When they do it, a thumbnail file is created in the windows environment. This in turn means that the resources have been modified and hence the error. We have always instructed our clients not to double click on the .app folder when they extract it from the zip file.