# App cannot be installed as its resources have been modified

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App not installed…because its resources have been modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819492/app-not-installed-because-its-resources-have-been-modified)

i got an error "App cannot be installed as its resources have been modified"
while installing the iphone app in my device.. What is the reason for this and how can i fix this? my device has iOS 4.3.3 and build is 4.2 is it problem?

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me also. I just updated the iTunes and then again it was giving error then I restarted it and it's working fine.

Comment: :(... sorry but it worked for me....