# "myApp" app was not installed because its resources have been modified error in ipad application

Tags: ipad, itunes, code-signing-certificate

I am working on a ipad application.I have created all the certificates now but when created the build. It works great on my ipad but when i send the build to the client and try to install on his ipad. It throws "myApp"app was not installed because its resources have been modified error even though he has installed the provisioning profile. Before this i send build many times it works great on both ipad. But just now ehen i add new default image and some more images in application. Those may not be making the error.

I am using the Debug as the active configuration. 
I am using Xcode 3.2.6 and ios 4.3 . We both have have ipad 4.3.1.

Kindly help me with this error.
i tried with the solutions on [App not installed...because its resources have been modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819492/app-not-installed-because-its-resources-have-been-modified)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you sending the build to him?  As a zip?  As an IPA?  Over the air?  When you say you have added a new default image, did you rebuild the app afterwards?

Comment: @Jim  I am sending as a zip.I delete previous build folder in project. i rebuild the app after adding the  image.

Comment: The accepted answer for the question you link to says that Windows can corrupt zips and suggests sending an ipa instead.  Did you try that?

Comment: i tried sending ipa but it is also not working. I have also newly created the application still it throws error. I also tried creating new certificates for signing.

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean?  Do you get exactly the same error?  How did you create the IPA?

Comment: I created the payload folder copy .app file in it then compress it and then change its extension to .ipa. Is there other way to do that....?

Comment: @Jim let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1007/discussion-between-abhitouchmagic-and-jim)

Comment: Hey jimmy i have solved the issue. It was a word(.doc)file which gets corrupted in windows system as it has "-" in its name. windows or the zip sytem. which turns "-" into some unknown characters. thank you for your help man....

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.  For future reference, Xcode can produce the IPA directly now with "Build and Archive" in Xcode 3, or simply "Archive" in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with included word file name as it contains some special character as "- and !" so the file gets diff name. I changes the name of the .doc file and it worked for me...
Thank you for support...